# Firebase Auth - progressive web app (polymer) offline mode

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication

Does firebase auth still keep the user in offline mode of a progressive web app ?

How does firebase auth works if the app is in offline ? Would like to know the two scenario.

1. User want to login for the first time during the app is in offline (app is using pouchDB  & CouchDB for sync)
2. User already signed in, but app became offline. Does this mode even still work with firebase auth ?

Regards,
Sowmyan

Answer (score 11):

Authenticating the user requires an active connection. There is no way for Firebase to authenticate your users without connecting to its servers.

Once the user is authenticated, the app will continue working when the user goes offline. Firebase Database operations will be reading from the local cache and writing to a queue. Once the connection is restored, the user's authentication token is (if needed) refreshed and the writes are sent to the server.

Comment: I'm new to using Firebase authentication and your answer helps. If you try to sign in when offline, the sign in process never completes. I was expecting it to fail by internally throwing a "not connected" exception or something. Since Firebase doesn't do that, I guess you are supposed to check the connection status before attempting to sign in?

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case.   An electron app, with a previously authenticated user, will authenticate that user again if the app is offline.

Comment: That's great to hear @lambinator. I'm not quite sure how Firebase would verify the user credentials without connecting to a server though. Can you write up an answer, showing how you made it work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen to clarify, of course, the user has to be online when they *first* sign in.   In our case, we generate a custom token on the server, and the client calls auth().signInWithCustomToken().   Once that's done, when our app starts offline, authentication succeeds and onAuthStateChanged() handler will still be called with the signed in user.

Comment: That is correct, and has always been the behavior. Only the initial sign-in requires an active connection to the servers. Sorry if my answer implied something else.